# Write multiple lines with quotes in a text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, quotes, writer

Hi Is there any easier way to write multiple lines in a file which has things like quotes in and other things like that or is the only way to do it like this

```
                Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(AppsDir & "EthIPChanger.bat")
            objwriter.WriteLine("@echo off")
            objwriter.WriteLine("netsh interface ip set address name=""" & "Local Area Connection""" & " static " & TB_EthIPAddress.Text & " " & TB_EthSubnetMask.Text & " " & TB_EthDefaultGateway.Text & " 1")
            objwriter.WriteLine("netsh interface ip set dns """ & "Local Area Connection""" & " static " & TB_EthDNS1.Text)
            objwriter.WriteLine("ipconfig /all > """ & AppsDir & "NetworkInfo.txt""")
            objwriter.WriteLine("echo hi > """ & AppsDir & "CheckLen.txt""")
            objwriter.Close()
```

I know if you are using python you can do """ and then do anything inside that and end it with """

Does anything like that exist in vb.net?

thanks

Comment: You can use *Chr(34)* instead of doing the double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use objwriter.Write - then you can supply the vbcrlf yourself - and then you can put multiple 'lines' in one write statement.

For example:

```
Dim str2write As string
str2write  = "firstline" and Chr(34) & Chr(34) & vbcrlf
str2write &= Chr(34) & "second line" and Chr(34) & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
objwriter.write(str2write)
objwriter.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with StringBuilder:

```
    Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(AppsDir & "EthIPChanger.bat")
    Dim textToWrite As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    With textToWrite
        .Append("@echo off")
        .AppendFormat("netsh interface ip set address name={0}Local Area Connection{0} static {1} {2} {3} 1", Chr(34), TB_EthIPAddress.Text, TB_EthSubnetMask.Text, TB_EthDefaultGateway.Text)
        .AppendFormat("netsh interface ip set dns {0}Local Area Connection{0} static {1}", Chr(34), TB_EthDNS1.Text)
        .AppendFormat("ipconfig /all > {0}{1}{2}{0}", Chr(34), AppsDir, TB_EthDNS1.Text)
        .AppendFormat("echo hi > {0}{1}{2}{0}", Chr(34), AppsDir, CheckLen.Text)
    End With

    objwriter.WriteLine(textToWrite.ToString)
    objwriter.Close()
```